# How to write integers to port using PySerial

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to write data to the first serial port, COM1, using PySerial.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(0)
print (ser.name)
ser.baudrate = 56700
ser.write("abcdefg")
ser.close()
```

ought to work. However, I need to send 28 bytes of integers constantly; in the form

```
255 255 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
```

on loop, with each integer using one byte of data.

Trying:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(0)
print (ser.name)
ser.baudrate = 56700
while True:
    ser.write(255 255 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000)
ser.close()
```

raises a `Syntax Error`.

How can you write integers to a serial port if [`write`](http://pythonhosted.org//pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write) only sends strings? How can I ensure that each number is sent as 8-bits?

There is [very little in the documentation for the class `serial`](http://pythonhosted.org//pyserial/pyserial_api.html), so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, writing `123 12 123 123 123` is not a valid Python syntax.

Create a list or a tuple with your integers: `values = (1,2,3,4,5)`

Now, we need to convert that data into a binary string that represents our values.

So here how we do it

```
import struct

values = (1,2,3,4,5)

string = b''

for i in values:
    string += struct.pack('!B',i)

# Now send the string to the serial port
```

Depending on how many bytes you want to use per number, you need to pack them differently. See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: +1. You can also do `s = struct.pack('!{0}B'.format(len(values)), *values)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, your code raises a new error: `TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly`. I have to say I haven't really used `struct` in Python, so you'll have to bear with me as I try to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I never used pySerial, but looking at the documentations it says, you can also send bytes.
So please have a look at: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes

Comment: I didn't realise Python had a built-in `bytes()` function. I will also try this when I get a chance - however, looking at the `PySerial` documentation `ser.write()` only takes string type arguments, and `bytes()` returns a mutable sequence type, so it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom I often use for this purpose (making a string from list of byte values) is:

```
''.join(map(chr,values))
```

and if you literally started out with a space delimited list of numbers, you can go a little crazy and use:

```
''.join(map(chr,map(int,values_string.strip().split())))
```

You can probably guess I like map.  It's even more fun with lambda functions!