# sending a string like "111#013" in python

Tags: python, c

i have written a code for my microcontroller using the c language and it functions in a way that when i send a 111#013 using the Hercules 3.2.8 app by HW group an led on my board lights up , but i dont know how to send the same thing using python here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial
port=serial.Serial(port='COM3',baudrate=115200,timeout=0)
def led1_on():
    port.write("111".encode(encoding="ascii"))
    print("111".encode(encoding="ascii"))
    port.write(13)
```

after this when i call led1_on() it doesn't work
explanation:the "111#013" means it sends a string 111 and then the number 13 , and the C code uses uart

This is the c code

```
int i=0,j=0,k=100,len=0;
float v;
char buffer[100];
char Tem[32];
char Rx_data[2],Rx_indx,Rx_Buffer[100],Transfer_cplt;
```

'

```
void chartoint(char *str)
{
  j=0;
  while (*str != 0)
  {
    if(*str <= '9' && *str >= '0')
    {j = j*10+(*str - '0');}
    str++;
  }
}

void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback (UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
  uint8_t i;
  if(huart->Instance==USART1)
  {
    chartoint(buffer);
    
    if(Rx_indx==0)
    {for(i=0;i<100;i++)
      Rx_Buffer[i]=0;}
    if(Rx_data[0]!=13)
    {Rx_Buffer[Rx_indx++]=Rx_data[0];}
    else
    {Rx_indx=0;
    Transfer_cplt=1;}
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1,Rx_data,1);
  }
}
```

'

```
if(Transfer_cplt)
{
  sprintf(buffer,"%s\r\n",Rx_Buffer);
  chartoint(buffer);
  //LED on-off
  if(j == 103)
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,1<<8,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  if(j == 113)
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,1<<8,GPIO_PIN_SET);
  if(j == 102)
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,1<<7,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  if(j == 112)
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,1<<7,GPIO_PIN_SET);
  if(j == 101)
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,1<<15,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  if(j == 111)
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,1<<15,GPIO_PIN_SET);
  //LED on-off
  if(j<=100)
    k=j*2;
  Transfer_cplt=0;
}
```

this isnt the latest version of the code and i've changed it a bit and it turns on more than one led, but this is probably useful,
the changed version works just fine when using the hercules app

Comment: What exactly is "111#013"? What sequence of bytes represent that?

Comment: It's hard to guess exactly what the C code does. Could we also see that?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? You seem to already send ``"111"`` and ``13``, why don't you send the intermediate ``"#0"`` as well?

Comment: I don't think `port.write(13)` is correct. See [How to write integers to port using PySerial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24956308/10077).

Comment: "111#013" means it sends a string 111 and then the number 13

Comment: adding the "#0" didn't help either

Comment: PySerial can only send bytes – neither the string ``"111"`` nor the number ``13``. What *bytes* does your C program expect? Must ``"111"`` be ASCII encoded (i.e. ``char[3]``)? Is ``13`` supposed to be signed or unsigned, and what size?

Comment: Please show us the C code as well

Comment: `#013` might refer to a CR (`"000\x0D"`)

Comment: i,ve also added a part of the c code please take a look

Comment: "Sending number 13" is very ambiguous. It could definitely mean a CR as I suggested earlier.

Comment: "Sending number 13" is very ambiguous. It could definitely mean a CR as I suggested earlier. i dont understand what this means, what do you think i should put in the code to make it work?